# Is it safe to use mmap and malloc to allocate memory in same program?

Tags: c, malloc, mmap

Till now what I understood is as follow:

1. `malloc` internally uses `sbrk` and `brk` to allocate memory by increasing top of heap.
2. `mmap` allocate memory in form of pages.

Now, let's say current top of `sbrk/malloc` is `0x001000`. And I use `mmap` to allocate a page of 4KB which is allocated at `0x0020000`. Later, if I used `malloc` multiple times and because of that it had to increase `sbrk` top. So, what if top reaches `0x002000`?

So, it will be great if someone can clarify the following.

1. Is above scenario possible?
2. If no than please point out flaw in my understanding of `malloc` and `mmap`.
3. If yes than I assume it is not safe to use it in this way. So, is there any other way to use both safely?

Thank you.

Comment: You're allowed to use both `malloc()` and `mmap()` in a single program; indeed, it would be hard to avoid it.  The implementation (library and kernel) will keep track of memory allocations and avoid problems.  Modern `malloc()` does not necessarily use `sbrk()` (it can use `mmap()` itself), and there are ways for it to keep track of what it had in use before, etc.  Plus, with 64-bit address spaces, things won't often be allocated so close together as to cause trouble, unless you try to specify the address where data is `mmap`'d.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for clearing my doubts.

Comment: Generally `sbrk` will fail (return an error) if it would impinge on mmap'ed memory.  So this may cause an sbrk-based malloc to prematurely fail (return a NULL from malloc) if you've mmaped something close to the sbrk heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. malloc is normally not implemented this way today... malloc used `sbrk(2)` in old implementations, when extending the data segment was the only way to ask the system for more virtual memory. Newer systems use `mmap(2)` if available, as they allow more flexibility when the virtual space is large enough (each `mmap`ed chunk is managed as a new data segment for the process requesting it).  `sbrk(2)` expands and shrinks the data segment, just like a stack.... so you have to be careful using `sbrk(2)` in case you are going to use it intermixed with a `sbrk` implementation of malloc.  The way malloc operates, normally disallows you to return any memory obtained with `sbrk(2)` if you intermix the calls... so you can only use it to grow the data segment safely.
2. `sbrk(2)` also allocates memory in pages.  Since paged virtual memory emerged, almost all o.s. allocation is made in page units.  Newer systems have even more than one pagesize (e.g. 4Kb and 2Mb sizes), so you can get benefit of that, depending on the application.
3. As 64bit systems get more and more use, there's no problem in allocating address space large enough to allow for both mecanisms to live together.  This is an advantage for a multiple heap malloc implementation, as memory is allocated and deallocated independently, and never in LIFO allocated order.

Malloc uses different approaches to allocate memory, but implementations normally try not to interfere with user `sbrk(2)` usage.  You have to be careful, that is, if you intermix `malloc(3)` calls with `sbrk(2)` in a `sbrk(2)` malloc system. then you run the risk of `sbrk(2)`ing over the malloc adjusted data segment, and breaking the malloc internal data structures.  You had better not to use `sbrk(2)` yourself if you are using a `sbrk(2)` implementation of malloc.

Finally, to answer your question, `mmap(2)` allocates memory as `malloc(3)` does, so malloc is not, and has not to be, aware of the allocated memory you did for your own use with `mmap(2)`.