# is there a way to prohibit gnu malloc on linux to alloc some memory area?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, glibc

Let's say I want to keep a huge memory area available for my own mmap (in my case for running my own virtual machine later).

By this way I want to be sure that any call to malloc, realloc etc won't allocate memory in this huge area.

Is there a way to prohibit malloc to allocate this area or am I obliged to write my own malloc, realloc, free functions, which won't use this area?

(For gnu malloc on linux)

Comment: Are you saying you want to reserve a *specific* range of addresses (if so, why?) or just to have a large enough amount of contiguous address space available for mapping?

Comment: Managing *physical* memory is done by the operating system, and no, you don't get to influence that. You don't even get to *see* the physical addresses. This seems a XY problem. Better rewrite the question to better explain what you want to achieve, because "prohibit malloc from allocating a specific memory area" is already quite some way down the wrong path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use mmap and malloc to allocate memory in same program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232038/is-it-safe-to-use-mmap-and-malloc-to-allocate-memory-in-same-program)

Comment: I want to have a large enough amount of contiguous address space available for mapping.
It s a very huge area of memory, it's impossible to allocate it (1024 Po) I want to later use it for some mmap.

Comment: It answer my question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to prohibit malloc to allocate this area or am I obliged to write my own malloc, realloc, free functions, which won't use this area?

[Glibc's allocator](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-GNU-Allocator.html) does have some [tunable parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html), but none of them are applicable to your objective.  Therefore, if you want to reserve memory for a future `mmap()` then the best available solution is to `mmap()` sufficient space preemptively, as early as possible in the program run.  If you prefer, you can do this as an anonymous mapping (i.e. not backed by any file).  When you subsequently want to replace that with another mapping, pass the address of the initial mapping and use the `MAP_FIXED` flag.  The new mapping will replace the original.

**Example:**

```
void *reserved_space = mmap(NULL, ALLOCATION_SIZE, PROT_NONE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

// ...

void *mapping =  mmap(reserved_space, ALLOCATION_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
```

Comment: Maybe it answer my question, but maybe no:as it s a very very huge area (1024Po) I want to reserve this memory without have this memory allocated, moreover, I will later use some part of this memory to mmap them (but not the huge area, only some part of it), is it possible. Thank you for your answer, I'll look in the mmap documentation.

Comment: @NicolasBourdon, whether a preemptive `mmap` is a solution that you're willing to implement is a different question.  What you asked was how to reserve an amount of address space from being used by glibc's `malloc()`.  Since you cannot configure the GNU allocator itself to do that, the only options are to not not use it or to put something in its way.

Comment: indeed it answer my question, thanks